# htmlのimgパスが読み込めなかった際のエラーハンドリングをしたい。

Tags: javascript, html

webアプリを作成しています。

htmlで画像のパスを最初は下記のように設定しています。

```
<img src="images/pinkguy.jpg" alt="">
```

その後JSで取得した別のパスに書き換えています。

```
<img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/dxezoC8w3GU/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="">
```

ここで画像のパスに画像がなく、取得できないエラーが発生した場合コンソールに

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

と出るのですが、その場合のエラーハンドリングをJSで行いたいのですがどのようにしてコードを書いたらよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onerror`属性を利用すると良いでしょう。

```html
<img src="/not/fount/image.jpg" onerror="alert('画像が見つかりませんでした。')">
```

参考

- https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Image_loading_errors

Comment: ありがとうございます。このような物があるのを知りませんでした。